# Вывод картинки в браузер из папки PHP

Tags: php, html

Вывожу картинку из папки в браузер

```html
<?php
$path2 = __DIR__ .'/img/1.jpg';
echo $img = '<img src="'.$path2.'"/>';
?>
```

Картинка не отображается, точнее отображается как "сломанная". Путь указан правильный и картинка в папке есть. В консоли пишет
"Not allowed to load local resource" 
Возможно есть другие способы вывести картинку?

Comment: Путь какой к файлу? `__DIR__`  - скорее всего возвращает не то что вам нужно.

Comment: Да, если не использовать DIR то картинка подгружается.

Answer (score 2):

в заголовках нужно указать что это фотка. и вывод файла вот так)) я когда то делал.

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

  $one= stream_get_contents(fopen("http://некоторвый ресурс  
 (сайт)/images/PHP7.jpg","rb"));

print_r(print_r);
```